# Sitecore WFFM: Issues Submitting form programmatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-mvc, sitecore-xdb

I have been trying to submit a my own form to WFFM. The form I created is identical to the one created with WFFM, that way all fields map correctly.

I began following the following steps: https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2015/05/18/programmatic-wffm-submissions/

I had to make minor changes to the code in order to get the `SubmitActionManager` to work

> The members of Sitecore.Form.Core.Submit.SubmitActionManager class
>   have been moved to the IActionExecutor interface.To obtain the
>   instance of this interface use the
>   (IActionExecutor)Factory.CreateObject ("wffm/wffmActionExecutor",
>   false) call.

Below is the code I have so far:

```cs
public void SubmitData(ContactUsFormModel data)
    {
        var results = new List<ControlResult>();
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufFirstNameID, "First Name", data.FirstName));
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufLastNameID, "Last Name", data.LastName));
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufEmailID, "Email", data.Email));
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufCompanyID, "Company", data.Company));
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufSubjectID, "Subject", data.Subject));
        results.Add(makeControlResult(Models.Constants._cufMessageID, "Message", data.Message));

        var formItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Models.Constants._contactUsFormID);
        var simpleForm = new SitecoreSimpleForm(formItem);
        var saveActionXml = simpleForm.FormItem.SaveActions;
        var actionList = Sitecore.Form.Core.ContentEditor.Data.ListDefinition.Parse(saveActionXml);

        var actionDefinitions = new List<ActionDefinition>();
        actionDefinitions.AddRange(actionList.Groups.SelectMany(x => x.ListItems).Select(li => new ActionDefinition(li.ItemID, li.Parameters) { UniqueKey = li.Unicid }));

        var SubmitActionManager = (IActionExecutor)Factory.CreateObject("wffm/wffmActionExecutor", false);
        Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionEvent sessionID = new Sitecore.Form.Core.WffmActionEvent();// SessionIDGuid

        var result = SubmitActionManager.ExecuteSaving(ID.Parse(Models.Constants._contactUsFormID), results.ToArray(), actionDefinitions.ToArray(), true, ID.Parse( sessionID.SessionIDGuid ));
    }

    private ControlResult makeControlResult(string fieldID, string fieldName, string fieldValue)
    {
        return new ControlResult(fieldName, fieldValue, string.Empty)
        {
            FieldID = fieldID,
            FieldName = fieldName,
            Value = fieldValue,
            Parameters = string.Empty
        };
    }
```

I wasnt sure where to get `Sitecore.Form.Core.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.SessionId` from to use it inside `ExecuteSaving`, so I used `WffmActionEvent`.
Also the guide I followed uses `Execute`, which is now deprecated, so I had to go with `ExecureSaving` (my best guess).

This however doesn't seem to be posting the submitted data into the databse. I am unable to see any of my submissions inside WFFM Form Reports or inside mongoDB.
The logs however state that the form is being saved to the database, not sure what the other warnings mean.

```
24688 17:20:39 WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current  is not initialized
24688 17:20:39 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\admin): [WFFM] Form {978DBF4C-0F56-45A8-A9AC-52EF8D995DDF} is saving to db
24688 17:20:39 WARN  [WFFM] Tracker.Current.Contact  is not initialized
24688 17:20:39 WARN  [WFFM]  Tracker.Current.Interaction  is not initialized
24688 17:20:39 WARN  [WFFM] CurrentSession  is not initialized
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are using `Sitecore 8` the form submission is stored in `MongoDB`. Sitecore's implementation of `MongoDB`, `xDB` mostly relies on tracking users, calling them `Contacts`.

Most data stored in `xDB` is linked to a `Contact` via a `ContactId`. The error messages you are finding in the log are stating that tracking is currently not enabled, therefore no `Contact` is present and there is no `Interaction` between the site and user.

Therefore you need to start `Sitecore.Tracker` I recommend using the following code

```cs
if (!Tracker.IsActive)
    Tracker.StartTracking();

if (!Tracker.IsActive || Tracker.Current.Contact == null)
{
    // handle no tracker and contact
}
```

Now that you have tracking working you need to use the correct ID for your `sessionID` variable.

The blog you are following is based on Sitecore 7, in Sitecore 8 `Sitecore.Form.Core.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.SessionId` is removed. I decompiled the Sitecore 7 code and Sitecore.Form.Core.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.SessionId ultimately uses `Tracker.CurrentVisit.VisitId`.

However this namespace has changed in Sitecore 8, Visits are now called interactions so instead of your variable SessionID you will want to use

```cs
Tracker.Current.Interaction.InteractionId;
```

That should resolve the issue you are currently having but you may need a bit more development to finish it off.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what prevented the code from being able to call the saved actions. However I am still left with one issue. I do not see the form data inside the forms reports / mongoDB, which prevents me from getting any form statistics/reports. There are no errors inside the logs. (I do see a warning but im pretty sure its completely unrelated, but ill still post it just in case)

Comment: > 25368 12:12:50 WARN  Authentication on CES Discovery service failed.
 Exception: System.Net.WebException
 Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
 Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.ExecuteRequest(String requestUri)
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.ResourceConnector`1.Request(String endpoint,  Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.CES.Discovery.EndpointSource.GetEndpoint(String > serviceName)

Comment: I tried adding SaveFormToDatabase call after doing ExecuteSaving call. And I do not see it getting stored.
`code`SubmitActionManager.SaveFormToDatabase(ID.Parse(Models.Constants._contactUsFormID), new AdaptedResultList(adaptedResults));

Comment: Ok, sorry for rambling on here. I think I spoke too soon on the last one. Not sure why I expected the results to show up in SQL instantly.... but they eventually get processed in and stored. So it is saving the forms correctly. I will eventually update the post with the proper solution.

Comment: Great - glad the results are displaying correctly. They won't appear straight away as they are stored in session and written to MongoDB when the User's session ends. Typically about 20 mins after last activity. Then the results are written to MongoDB and ultimately in the reporting SQL database. This design choice is to save expensive repeated calls to Mongo